# Canvas draw image blocked by code below it

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, html5-canvas

Hi I have a following function

```
render = function ( ctx, img, W, H ) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, W, H, 0, 0, W, H);
}
```

I am calling the function from another function

```
renderImage(ctx, img, width, height);
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++) {
    // en expensive for loop
}
```

The problem I am facing the image doesn't load in the browser until the for loop finishes executing, however it is not clear why the image wait to load until the for loop finishes. Anyone can help? How can I make it load without waiting for the loop to finish executing?

Comment: `context.drawImage` should be `ctx.drawImage`

Comment: When you say "*doesn't load*" you mean "doesn't render" right? It's because this is how javascript works. It's single threaded and if you perform a for loop like that it will block anything until the execution process has finished. Split your loop in multiple smaller ones, call them with a timeout or within a requestAnimationFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded so the browser is prevented from updating the screen while the loop is running.

To solve give the browser a moment to breath using a delay. This will of course make the code run asynchronous so a callback mechanism is possibly required depending on the code's next move.

**Example:**

```
renderImage(ctx, img, width, height);

setTimeout(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++) {
    // en expensive for loop
  }
  // call next step
}, 9);   // delay some arbitrary ms
```

If the loop is long-running you could consider splitting it up in several segments or use a `WebWorker`.

See these answers for how to split the loop:

- [Why is this for loop blocking if it is called afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424321/why-is-this-for-loop-blocking-if-it-is-called-afterwards/21424716#21424716)
- [Converting Uint8Array crashing browser for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989796/converting-uint8array-crashing-browser-for-large-files/29991479#29991479)

Bonus tip: you don't have to use the clipping parameters to draw a resized image, just provide width and height:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, W, H);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't work however `setTimeout` work perfectly. Any idea why?

Comment: @MuhammadRaihanMuhaimin should be the same in principle, the only difference is that setTimeout need a timeout value specified ( >= 4 ms). If older browser you may need a polyfill for rquestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @K3N I am using chrome. If I remove the timeout variable and replace it with window.requestAnimationFrame it stopped working until the loop finished.

Comment: @MuhammadRaihanMuhaimin I'm looking at my example to see if I am overlooking something obvious. In any case, for this scenario the rAF is not essential, setTimeout will do fine. Temporary removing raf example.

Comment: @MuhammadRaihanMuhaimin the cause is likely being that any code between previous monitor update and next is included despite from calling raf in between the two code segments. I.e. raf won't skip to *next* frame update (which was the assumption). This means raf would have to be called in two stages, one to draw the image, then add a new request from within that call to then do the loop. Which is not so elegant... The correct approach here would therefor be to use setTimout; and the initial statement about raf would be incorrect (permanently removed from answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to load the image first , and then run draw?

```
var img = new Image();
var i = 0;
img.onload = function(){
    //draw...
    animate();
};
img.src = 'source.jpg';
function animate(){
    if(i<10000000) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    }
}

function render(){
    //draw
}
```

Comment: Yes I followed the above approach but that doesn't work

Comment: Did you try with 'requestAnimationFrame'?

Comment: The 'for' loop is too fast , you should use methods designed for drawing, like 'setinterval' or 'requestAnimationFrame'
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame